# Get line count in textblock- windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a **textblock in a Data template** in which I am displaying **data through binding**. Initially I need to show data upto three lines in textblock. For more data there is **See more option tapping which expands the textblock**.

Upto this things are done. The main problem I am facing is **if the data size is not more than three lines, I don't have to shoe see more option**.

**How do I get to know that my data consumes just 1 or 2 lines of textblock**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have view model bound to your template

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string MyBoundText { get { .. }; set { .. }; }
]
```

You can just create another property:

```
public int LinesNo => this.MyBoundText.Split('\n').Length; 
//remember about null-check and other edge-cases
```

I assume you have in your xaml somewhere:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyBoundText}"></TextBox>
```

SO, create own converter:

```
class Button1VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int mode = (int)value;
        if (mode <= (int)parameter)
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        else
            return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then bind it with your button:

```
<Button Content="Show more...">
    <Button.Visibillity>
        <Binding Path="LinesNo "
                 Converter="{StaticResource Button1VisibilityConverter }">
            <Binding.ConverterParameter>
                <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
            </Binding.ConverterParameter>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Visibillity>
</Button>
```

(Remember to place converter as static resoruce before).

**Warning: not tested, it is only idea / hint.**

Comment: Thank you. But I think you are counting lines on basis of "/n". But I don't receive any "/n" char in my text. I need to count the lines on the basis of wrapping in textblock.